# How to manage @ObservedObject and @EnvironmentObject on same Struct?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

When `EnvironmentObject` is update at same time `ObservedObject` is initialized again. So, `Name` value is blank every time when `@EnvironmentObject` updates.

```swift
struct MenuView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var order: Order
    @ObservedObject var model = DetailsModel()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Name: \(self.model.name)")

                Button(action:{
                    self.model.name = "Arjun"
                }) {
                    Text("Set Name")
                }.padding(.bottom, 30.0)
                
                Button(action:{
                    self.order.add(item: "item")
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "cart.badge.plus")
                    Text("Add to cart")
                }.padding(.bottom, 30.0)
            }
        }
    }
}

// DetailsModel
class DetailsModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var name:String = ""

}
```

My question is How to mange `@ObservedObject` value once `@EnvironmentObject` updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SwiftUI 2.0**

Make it `@StateObject`, like

```
struct MenuView: View {

@EnvironmentObject var order: Order
@StateObject var model = DetailsModel()
...
```

**SwiftUI 1.0**

Inject it externally via constructor (having for it own life-cycle)

```
struct MenuView: View {

@EnvironmentObject var order: Order
@ObservedObject var model: DetailsModel
...
```